# proper value to type in the fast enumeration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, cocoa, fast-enumeration

i have a model (core data) set up, called Animals. i have to access this in a specific order and to do so i use the code listed below. what am i supposed to type instead of the XXXXXXXXX in the for loop?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [animalscontroller.arrangedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
for (XXXXXXXX *a in sortedArray)
{

...........    

}
```

i have been told that i have to put the name of the model, so in this case "Animals" but that gives me an error saying that the variable Animals is not declared. i am pretty green on cocoa programming.

thank you

Best regards

Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Animals" is your entity name, not your *class* name.  Unless you've specified that "Animals" has a custom class, the class name you want here is `NSManagedObject`, or you can just use `id`.

Comment: thank you! mind telling me also how i could access the value "header" of my model inside the for loop? a.managedObjectModel.header? or something like that?

Comment: If you're casting to an `id` or `NSManagedObject`, you can use `valueForKey:`.  If you want to be able to use the dot-notation to access the properties, you have to either declare them in a subclass or add them as a category to `NSManagedObject`... read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW7

Comment: yayyyyyyy it worked! thank you very much! :) you deffinetly made my day... :)